# Relation between singular values of a data matrix and the eigenvalues of its covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I have a $m \times n$ data matrix $X$, ($m$ instances and $n$ features) on which I calculate the Covariance matrix

$$C := \frac{1}{(m-1)} X'X.$$

Then I perform eigenvalue decomposition of $C$, and store the eigenvalues $E$.

In another application I also require the singular values of $X$, so I perform SVD on $X$, and store the singular values $S$. Now I want to know how the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix $C$ are related to the singular values of the data matrix $X$.

Wikipedia in its [SVD article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) says:

> The non-zero singular values of $X$ (found on the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$) are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of both $X'X$ and $XX'$.

However, there is no mention of the connection between the non-zero singular values of $X$ and the eigenvalues of $C$.

I tried dividing the squares of the singular values of $X$ by $m-1$, but then there is a huge difference between $\frac{S_1^2}{m-1}$ and $E_1$, where $S_1$ refers to first sigular value of $X$, and $E_1$ is the first eigenvalue of $C$. The remaining values match.

Can anyone point out to why this is happening? I used `rand` function in Matlab to create $X$, so the elements of  $X$ are pseudorandom numbers in $(0,1)$ drawn from the uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting such an error because the input matrix to SVD needs to be mean centered. This is because when we do the eigenvalue decomposition on the Covariance matrix $C$, the data input to $C$ is mean centered.

So the right way is to mean center the data and then apply SVD, then take the square of singular values and divide by $m-1$. Then $E = \frac{S^2} {m -1 }$. holds perfectly.

So I will consider this question as solved.!

Answer (score 1):

Let singular values of $X$ be $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma 2 \ge \sigma_r > \sigma_{r+1} = \cdots = 0$, and let the eigenvalues of $C$ be $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n$. Then, indeed,

$$\lambda_k = \frac{\sigma_k^2}{m-1}.$$

To see this, let $X = U \Sigma V^T$, where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, and $\Sigma = \mathop{\rm diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots)$. Then

$$C = \frac{1}{m-1} X^T X = V \left( \frac{1}{m-1} \Sigma^T \Sigma \right) V^T.\tag{1}$$

Since $\Sigma$ is rectangular diagonal, and $(1)$ is a similarity relation,

$$\frac{1}{m-1} \Sigma^T \Sigma = \mathop{\rm diag} \left( \frac{\sigma_1^2}{m-1}, \frac{\sigma_2^2}{m-1}, \dots \right) = \mathop{\rm diag} ( \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots).$$

Now, the important thing here is that this is **theory**. In practice, matrix multiplication is not numerically stable and the errors may occur. Furthermore, they may be very significant in terms of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$. This is one of the main purposes of SVD: accurate computation of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$ (without actually computing the product $X^TX$).

However, there may also be an error in your code, since these errors usually happen with the smallest eigenvalues.

If this happens only sometimes, give an example of one such $X$ (of small order, please) along with your eigenvalues of $C$ and singular values of $X$, so we can check what is going on. If it happens all the time, give us your code, as it may have a bug.